# Is there a comprehensive list of Ancient Greek mathematical writings?

Tags: biographical-details, reference-request, antiquity, greek-mathematics

Much of the Ancient Greek's mathematical philosophy texts have survived from antiquity and passed to modern times. Also, texts previously thought to be lost are being occasionally rediscovered (Notably the [Archimedes Palimpsest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes_Palimpsest) and [Ptolemy's Meteoroscope](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00407-022-00302-w)). Unfortunately, there are also writings lost in time, that we know of only by reference.

I am looking for a comprehensive list of the *titles* of Ancient Greek manuscripts from the millennium of 7th century BC to 6th century AD. Does such a list exist?

Details for each title should include: authorship, timeframe, whether it be extant or lost, accessibility of manuscript, availability of translations, and topics covered.

---

#### Resources

**Extant Writings and Fragments**

- [Perseus Digital Library](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/collection?collection=Perseus:collection:Greco-Roman): Contains the English translations of a few well known texts.
- [Open Greek and Latin](https://opengreekandlatin.github.io/First1KGreek/): A more expansive base, with purely Greek and Latin. However, user experience is difficult.

(Diagrams not included)

**Lost Writings**

- [An list of lost works via Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_literary_work): By no means a complete list.

These references I mentioned are fine, but not extremely suitable or simple.

---

If such a comprehensive list does not exist, I will put the work in to create one. Are other scholars are having similar troubles dealing with the disorganization of classical writings?

Comment: At least, not in print, historians specializing in ancient mathematics refer to no such list. You can piece some of it together based on Heath's History of Greek Mathematics (2 volumes) and Katz's Sourcebook in the Mathematics of Ancient Greece and the Eastern Mediterranean.

Comment: @Conifold Thank you! I have Heath's work, and will look into getting Katz's work.

Comment: For the early period, see also [Zhmud, The Origin of the History of Science in Classical Antiquity](https://www.academia.edu/3480555/The_Origin_of_the_History_of_Science_in_Classical_Antiquity). He devotes much space to mathematics and secondary sources like Eudemus, which are the only reason we know of many lost works.

Comment: Here's another that might be helpful - "A source book in Greek Science" by Morris R. Cohen and I. E. Drabkin: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.279430